# Temporary NSTextView calls custom NSColor subclass, calling UI in background thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nstextstorage

I am measuring text block heights in a background thread. For some reason, if this happens when the application has just started, the thread makes a call to a NSColor subclass called `DynamicColor` which needs to be in main thread, as it checks if the app is in dark mode or not.

The class where the background thread is running should not have any reference to `DynamicColor`, but still, when the `NSTextStorage` is allocated, DynamicColor gets called. It causes an error for making UI calls from background task.

I have no idea how the `NSTextStorage` could be making call to some class it doesn't know to exist. Only my `NSDocument` subclass has referral to it, none of the other classes should be unaware of it.

Call to background thread in `NSDocument`:

```c
- (void)updatePreviewAndUI:(bool)updateUI {         
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        Preview *preview = [[PreviewCreator alloc] initWithScript:script];
    });
}
```

The background thread goes over numerous elements containing string data and calculates their heights.

```c
+ (NSInteger)heightForString:(NSString *)string font:(NSFont *)font maxWidth:(NSInteger)maxWidth lineHeight:(CGFloat)lineHeight
{
    // The error occurs here
    NSTextStorage   *textStorage   = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:string attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font }];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:NSMakeSize(maxWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    ...
}
```

Call to `DynamicColor` happens when `NSTextStorage` is allocated. I was able to avoid crashes by checking if we are on the main thread in `DynamicColor`, but I'm worried about the cause of the error.

`DynamicColor` is a `NSColor` subclass. Here are the relevant parts:

```c
#define FORWARD( PROP, TYPE ) \
- (TYPE)PROP { return [self.effectiveColor PROP]; }

- (NSColor *)effectiveColor
{
    if (NSApp) {
        // Call to Application delegate causes the thread error
        if ([(ApplicationDelegate*)[NSApp delegate] isForcedLightMode]) {
            if (self.aquaColor != nil) return self.aquaColor;
        }
        else if ([(ApplicationDelegate*)[NSApp delegate] isForcedDarkMode]) {
            if (self.darkAquaColor != nil) return self.darkAquaColor;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried setting a plain `NSColor` as the `NSTextContainer` foreground color, but it didn't help. The error does not occur every time when running the app, and in a test environment I was unable to reproduce the problem. Also, it's only the *first* time a text container is allocated, when this happens.

Comment: Could the issue be that there’s an implicit check on NSForegroundColor looking at +NSColor.textColor ( or whatever the system text color name is)

Comment: And maybe the solution is to give it a non dynamic foreground color explicitly at that point.

Comment: I suspected that, too, but it has no effect. I have a feeling that somehow this is connected to my application's singleton class, because the error only happens while loading a document. The weird part is, that the whole calculation is called from a class which also should not have any reference to my custom color subclass.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: I updated the question with more details, but reproducing the issue turned out to be very hard, unfortunately, as it happens unexpectedly.